# update query on sQlite not working below is onUpgrade method

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ADD COLUMN usertype BOOLEAN NOT NULL default false");

}
```

this code is not working kindly recommend me improvement if any

Comment: What does "not working" mean to you?

Comment: Did you remember to increase the value of the **DATABASE_VERSION** constant?

Comment: in code where I have to update new database version?

Comment: It's normally in the declaration section of your database helper class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION_1 = 1;
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION_2 = 2;
```

Use this code in onUpgrade() method

```
if(DATABASE_VERSION_2 > DATABASE_VERSION_1)
{
 db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ADD COLUMN usertype BOOLEAN NOT NULL 
 default false");

}
```

In the constructor you will also need to make a change like this:
You need to place DATABASE_VERSION_2 instead of DATABASE_VERSION_1 then onUpgrade() method will be called.

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION_2);
```

Comment: do I have to update new database version? if yes then where and how? my current database version is 1